# Modal not trigger on click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to trigger my modal to pop up and for some reason, it keeps saying that it isn't a function. I followed the steps on bootstrap, and saw a couple of similar questions but they haven't worked out for me. Is there something else that I am missing in my javascript? I recreated the minimum reproducible code with my html and js. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StudioPick</title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/studiodash.css">

    <script>
        function menuToggle() {
            const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".menu");
            toggleMenu.classList.toggle("active");
        }

        // SignOut
        function signOut() {
            auth.signOut();
            alert("SignOut Successfully from System");

            window.location.href = "login.html?error";
            alert("No active user please sign or sign up.");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>




    <!-- Modal -->
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-lg"
            viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M8 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-5h-5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h5v-5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 2Z">
            </path>
        </svg>
        Add Service
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





    <script>
        var myModal = document.getElementById('myModal')

        myModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            if (!data) {
                return event.preventDefault() // stops modal from being shown
            }
        })
    </script>



    <!----More Bootstrap--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!----More Bootstrap--->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given code is working for me. It is opening the modal. There must be some other script that is creating some issues.
[image]

Comment: Nope. I even created a separate test page with just the code that i have and i still get the same error. I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')". It even shows it on the terminal in the snippet

Comment: @Grmln you're getting that error with the code you posted here? Works fine for me.

Comment: Also your `var myModal` is looking for ID `myModal` but your modal has id `exampleModal`

Comment: Yup, I skipped right over it when i reread it. Thanks!